# Vector Shapefile with no known coordinate system. How can I find out and transform it?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I was looking for a shapefile for watersheds in Ethiopia and I found the following data set

https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/watersheds-ethiopia/resource/0e6b847c-b9e6-464e-9141-90172ed49842

I can open it up in a new project shapefile, but QGIS assumes that it is WGS 84, and I can view it.

[image: Image of watersheds]

However, I can't work out what the real-CRS is, and I want to overlay it with other data sets whose CRS I do know. Is there a way to work out what the CRS is, so I can transform it to a CRS that is aligned with my other shapefiles?

Comment: May you will find this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190115/is-it-possible-to-restore-lost-prj-files useful

Comment: Agree it's not a decimal degree based CRS,as `ogrinfo -so eth_watshed.shp eth_watshed` gives extent of `Extent: (-161882.562500, 376388.125000) - (1495282.875000, 1645935.625000)`

Comment: It's definitely a m-based CRS, so you have to go through all possible candidates. Check for country based CRS and viable UTM-strips.

Comment: Most likely one of `EPSG::20136, EPSG::20137, EPSG::20138, EPSG::32636, EPSG::32637, EPSG::32638`

Comment: One last question - it would seem that it is either EPSG::20137 (Adinan UTM 37N) and EPSG::32637 (WGS / UTM 37N). How can I tell the dfference between them?


What I see is that the Adinan seems to have limits on its latitude extents E

Extent: 36.00, 3.40, 42.00, 22.01
Proj4: +proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=clrk80 +towgs84=-166,-15,204,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

Whereas the WGS 84 / UTM 34 seems to extend much further north. 

Extent: 36.00, 0.00, 42.00, 84.00
Proj4: +proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just Googled "Coorindate Reference System for Ethiopia" and the top result was `EPSG:20137 - Adindan / UTM zone 37N`.

I set the CRS to that and stuck it into QGIS and it looks pretty good:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that's it. I'm trying to press the green tick but it doesn't seem to work. Let me try again, as it seems to be the right answer